# Unresolved External symbol __imp__curl_easy_XXX

Tags: c++, curl, visual-studio-2013, libcurl

Okay so I'm trying to install but I'm stuck at launching getting the following 5 errors:

```
unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_cleanup referenced in function _main
unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_init referenced in function _main
unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_perform referenced in function _main
unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_setopt referenced in function _main
unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_strerror referenced in function _main
```

Using the sample code:

```
CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
        /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
```

Comment: Do you use static or dynamic `libcurl`?

Comment: @Vitaliy I'm new to c++ and not sure :P
I got this one from curl.haxx.se (Win32 - Generic: Win32 zip 7.40.0)

Comment: @Vitaliy I'm afraid they've just missed to link against either of these.